# Get all vertices with a specific property, label and id along the path

Tags: nosql, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have following structure in a Janusgraph database:

```
gremlin> continent = g.addV("continent").property("name", "Europe").next()
gremlin> country = g.addV("country").property("name", "France").next()
gremlin> region = g.addV("region").property("name", "Ile-de-France").next()
gremlin> departement = g.addV("departement").property("name", "Hauts-de-Seine").next()
gremlin> city = g.addV("city").property("name", "Saint-Cloud").next()
gremlin> g.V(continent).addE('is_part_of').to(country).iterate()
gremlin> g.V(country).addE('is_part_of').to(region).iterate()
gremlin> g.V(region).addE('is_part_of').to(departement).iterate()
gremlin> g.V(departement).addE('is_part_of').to(city).iterate()
```

I did to get the property `name` from all vertices from **city** to **continent** from the following query:

```
gremlin> g.V(city).emit().repeat(inE("is_part_of").outV().simplePath()).path().unfold().dedup().values("name")
==>Saint-Cloud
==>Hauts-de-Seine
==>Ile-de-France
==>France
==>Europe
```

But I would like to get also the `id` and the `label` of every returned vertex.
I tried to use `valueMap(true)` instead of `values("name")` step to get all properties including `id` and `label`, but big part of vertices contain lot of properties which could be heavy in the level of performance.
Is it possible to get those values from each vertex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do `valueMap(true, 'name')`

```
gremlin> g.V(city).emit().repeat(inE("is_part_of").outV().simplePath()).
......1>   path().
......2>   unfold().
......3>   dedup().
......4>   valueMap(true,'name')
==>[id:8,label:city,name:[Saint-Cloud]]
==>[id:13,label:is_part_of]
==>[id:6,label:departement,name:[Hauts-de-Seine]]
==>[id:12,label:is_part_of]
==>[id:4,label:region,name:[Ile-de-France]]
==>[id:11,label:is_part_of]
==>[id:2,label:country,name:[France]]
==>[id:10,label:is_part_of]
==>[id:0,label:continent,name:[Europe]]
```

Comment: Thank you @stephen. I just added the `select()` step to get only vertex properties since my initial query returns also the edge metadata: `g.V(city).emit().repeat(inE("is_part_of").outV().as("a").simplePath()).path().unfold().dedup().select("a").dedup().valueMap(true, 'name')`

Comment: you shouldn't have to do that. just do `repeat(__.in('is_part_of')).simplePath())`rather than`inE().outV()`.